# zenity failing in crontab but working in shell

Tags: cron, zenity

I'm trying to run a script that calls zenity from a crontab and it fails. The script works well from the command line.

I do pass the DISPLAY in the crontab:

```
* * * * * DISPLAY=:1 bin/myscript.sh > /tmp/debug.txt 2>&1
```

In the debug logs, I get:

```
This option is not available. Please see --help for all possible usages.
```

Trying to remove the options, I found that the problematic is "--text" because the following doesn't work:

```
zenity --warning --title "Fais gaffe" --text "Bientôt plus de batterie"
```

But the following does:

```
zenity --warning --title "Fais gaffe"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out that the issue is in the content of the text.

I'm not sure what the difference is between running the script in the command line or in crontab, but the `ô` is causing the issue.

Replacing it by a `o`, the command works fine in the crontab too:

```
zenity --warning --title "Fais gaffe" --text "Bientot plus de batterie"
```

Comment: Perhaps your interactive shell has locale settings that the very simple sh used by cron lacks.